# Arrays and loops in zsh

Tags: zsh, array

I am trying to learn loops and array manipulation in `zsh`.

Say I have two arrays in zsh with the same **unknown** # of elements and each of them containing a list of paths, e.g.

```
LOCAL_ARRAY=($LOCAL_PATH_1 $LOCAL_PATH_2 $LOCAL_PATH_3)
REMOTE_ARRAY=($REMOTE_PATH_1 $REMOTE_PATH_2 $REMOTE_PATH_3)
```

I would like to iterate through both arrays simultaneously with a common index, so that I can do something like:

```
cd $LOCAL_PATH_i
hg pull $REMOTE_PATH_i
```

in each iteration. How can I do this in zsh?

Also, I have searched for loop control and arrays in the [zsh documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/zsh_toc.html) but had little success. Is there a good **tutorial** that introduces the basics of **loops**, **arrays**, etc. in zsh?  Something for people with little bash or shell-scripting experience but  with a background in programming?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Section [15.2.1 “Array Subscripts”](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Array-Subscripts) says that arrays can be index with `[exp]` (where `exp` is a numeric expression) and that elements start at index 1 (0 if `KSH_ARRAYS` is set).

Section [14.3 “Parameter Expansion”](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) says that the syntax `${#array_name}` will expand to the number of elements of an array.

Section [6.3 “Complex Commands”](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Grammar.html#Complex-Commands) gives the syntax for a numeric `for` loop (as in C):
`for (( initExpr ; testExpr ; stepExpr )) do … done`.

Putting them all together:

```
for (( i = 1; i <= $#LOCAL_PATH; i++ )) do
    ( # subshell to contain the effect of the chdir
        cd $LOCAL_PATH[i]
        hg pull $REMOTE_PATH[i]
    )
done
```

Or, if you are using `KSH_ARRAYS`, then this:

```
for (( i = 0; i < ${#LOCAL_PATH[@]}; i++ )) do
    ( # subshell to contain the effect of the chdir
        cd ${LOCAL_PATH[i]}
        hg pull ${REMOTE_PATH[i]}
    )
done
```

Using `KSH_ARRAYS` makes arrays start with index 0, requires the use of braces for array expressions, and interprets `$array` as `$array[0]` (requiring a change to the array length expression). The syntax changes required by `KSH_ARRAY` will also work without `KSH_ARRAY`, but you still have to adjust the logic for the different index range (1 through N versus 0 through N-1).

Answer (score 3):

You could [*zip*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) the two arrays and loop over them with two variables like:

```
LOCAL_ARRAY=($LOCAL_PATH_1 $LOCAL_PATH_2 $LOCAL_PATH_3)
REMOTE_ARRAY=($REMOTE_PATH_1 $REMOTE_PATH_2 $REMOTE_PATH_3)

for local remote (${LOCAL_ARRAY:^REMOTE_ARRAY}) (
  cd $local &&
   hg pull $remote
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the two arrays, you can also combine them into an associated array (think of “hash” in Ruby/Perl, “map” in C++, “HashMap” in Java, or “dict” in Python):

```bsh
typeset -A remotes
remotes=(
  local1 remote1
  local2 remote2
)

for local remote in "${(@kv)remotes}"  # (kv) means key and value
                                       # and (@) within quotes is to
                                       # preserve empty ones (in your
                                       # case ${(kv)remotes} would be
                                       # enough as file paths are not
                                       # meant to be empty).
do
    (
        cd $local &&
          hg pull $remote
    )
done
```

Note: the syntax highlight might be misleading.

Comment: Or `for local (${(k)remotes}) (cd $local && hg pull $remotes[$local])` otherwise there's little benefit in using an *associative* array.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yeah, that’s true. I guess I wrote it that way due to a habit from other languages (such as C++) where performance matters. (Doing lookup for N times can be expensive.)